# OWC PivotTable toolbox item grayed out for WebForm

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, pivot-table, office-web-components

I'm trying to build a Pivottable on a webform in vb.net 2005 using OWC. I have added the Pivottable item to the toolbox, but it is grayed out and so I cant use it. If I develop a Winform instead of a Webform then the toolbox items are there and work correctly.

Comment: good question please ask more

Answer (score 1):

The "Office Web Components" are ActiveX controls. You cannot add them to a web page through the WebForms designer. That is why they are disabled (grayed out). WinForms can host ActiveX controls, and that is why the components are not disabled when designing forms.

To add the PivotTable to a web page, use the `object` element and specify the `classid` of "clsid:0002E55A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046". See samples below.

- *Microsoft Office 2000 Web Components Basics* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155769(office.10).aspx

---

#### Sample

Following is the resulting code when adding the PivotTable to a web page using FrontPage 2003.

```
<object classid="clsid:0002E55A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" id="PivotTable1">
    <param name="XMLData" value="&lt;xml xmlns:x=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel&quot;&gt;
 &lt;x:PivotTable&gt;
  &lt;x:OWCVersion&gt;11.0.0.8304         &lt;/x:OWCVersion&gt;
  &lt;x:DisplayScreenTips/&gt;
  &lt;x:CubeProvider&gt;msolap.2&lt;/x:CubeProvider&gt;
  &lt;x:CacheDetails/&gt;
  &lt;x:PivotView&gt;
   &lt;x:IsNotFiltered/&gt;
  &lt;/x:PivotView&gt;
 &lt;/x:PivotTable&gt;
&lt;/xml&gt;">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="8">
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#336699" height="25" width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#666666" width="85%"><font face="Tahoma" color="white" size="4"><b>&nbsp; Missing: Microsoft Office Web Components</b></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="15">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="500px"><br>
    <font face="Tahoma" size="2">This page requires the Microsoft Office Web Components.<p align="center"> <a href="D:/ENGLISH/OFFICE_SYSTEM/OFFICEPRO2003/files/owc11/setup.exe">Click here to install Microsoft Office Web Components.</a>.</p></font><p><font face="Tahoma" size="2">This page also requires Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.01 or higher.</p><p align="center"><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/default.htm"> Click here to install the latest Internet Explorer</a>.</font><br>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</object>
```

Following is the resulting code when adding the PivotTable to a web pge using SharePoint Designer 2007.

```
<object classid="clsid:0002E55A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" id="PivotTable1">
    <param name="XMLData" value="&lt;xml xmlns:x=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel&quot;&gt;
 &lt;x:PivotTable&gt;
  &lt;x:OWCVersion&gt;11.0.0.8304         &lt;/x:OWCVersion&gt;
  &lt;x:DisplayScreenTips/&gt;
  &lt;x:CubeProvider&gt;msolap.2&lt;/x:CubeProvider&gt;
  &lt;x:CacheDetails/&gt;
  &lt;x:PivotView&gt;
   &lt;x:IsNotFiltered/&gt;
  &lt;/x:PivotView&gt;
 &lt;/x:PivotTable&gt;
&lt;/xml&gt;" />
</object>
```

Following is the resulting code using Microsoft Excel 2003's Save As Web Page, with "Add interactivity" checked.

```
<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
<!--The following information was generated by Microsoft Office Excel's Publish
as Web Page wizard.-->
<!--If the same item is republished from Excel, all information between the DIV
tags will be replaced.-->
<!----------------------------->
<!--START OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD -->
<!----------------------------->

<div id="Book1_31522" align=center x:publishsource="Excel"><object
 id="Book1_31522_Spreadsheet"
 classid="CLSID:0002E559-0000-0000-C000-000000000046">
 <param name=DisplayTitleBar value=false>
 <param name=Autofit value=true>
 <param name=DataType value=XMLData>
 <param name=XMLData
 value="[AMJ - REMOVED FOR POSTING]">
 <p style='margin-top:100;font-family:Arial;font-size:8.0pt'>To use this Web
 page interactively, you must have MicrosoftÂ® Internet Explorer 5.01 Service
 Pack 2 (SP2) or later and the Microsoft Office 2003 Web Components.</p>
 <p style='margin-top:100;font-family:Arial;font-size:8.0pt'>See the <a
 href="http://r.office.microsoft.com/r/rlidmsowcpub?clid=1033&amp;p1=Excel">Microsoft
 Office Web site</a> for more information.</p>
</object></div>


<!----------------------------->
<!--END OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD-->
<!----------------------------->
```